# Linking OpenCV to a shared library "mylib", `undefined reference to ...` errors

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dependencies, shared-libraries

I am trying to use OpenCV-2.4.13 shared objects (`libopencv_core.so`,`libopencv_imgproc.so` etc.) in `mylib.so`.
These OpenCV shared objects are compiled and installed with standard build procedure (make, make install) and I confirmed that they are located in `/usr/local/lib`, they can be used directly with an application without any problem.

I am using Qt 5.8 on Ubuntu 16.04 for building process.

In `mylib.so`, I use common `cv::Mat` functions. Looking at the similar questions, I have already skimmed [this article](http://www.kaizou.org/2015/01/linux-libraries/), it suggests either using `-rpath` or `-rpath-link` options during linking `mylib.so` with an application. I also did read [this article](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) from Qt and applied the suggested method when building `mylib.so`: adding a `a_global.h` and defining an export symbol as `Q_DECL_EXPORT`.

I am providing .pro file for `mylib.so` below.

```
QT       -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = mylib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += a.cpp
HEADERS += a.h external_libraries.h a_global.h

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/include"
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core\
-lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc\
-lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl\
-lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_video\
-lopencv_videostab
```

Also, here is the .pro file for a dummy test application.

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = apptest
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "/home/foo/mylib/"  #this is where `a.h` is
LIBS +=        "/home/foo/mylib/build/mylib.so.1.0.0"

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += "-Wall"
QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/lib"
QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs"
```

You can see that I am providing `/usr/local/lib` as the `-rpath-link` where OpenCV shared objects reside. I am also instructing the linker to ignore unresolved symbols from shared libraries, which is suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055569/linking-with-dynamic-library-with-dependencies) and documented [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).
The "right way" according to many sources is not to link OpenCV (or any dependency) in application, because this causes overlinking. In `apptest`, when I don't link OpenCV, I get the following linker error:

```
undefined reference to cv::Mat::deallocate()
undefined reference to cv::fastFree(void)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Looking at the error, my intuition is, somehow `-rpath-link` is not doing what it is supposed to do.

I was not able to resolve this, I decided to deliberately link OpenCV with `apptest` just to see what happens. What happens is awkward: it compiles and links without errors (whether I provide `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-shared-libs` option or not). But when I run the app, it crashes without any exceptions from OpenCV; `cv::imread` operation does not work as expected, rows and cols of image is zero.

I checked both `apptest` and `mylib.so` with `readelf -d`. Nothing strange occured to me,

- `mylib.so` depends on `libQt5Core` and `libopencv_*` and it has the right SONAME entry.
- `apptest` depends on `mylib.so`,`libQt5Core` and also `libopencv_*` when I did the deliberate linking.

I also tried to debug `apptest` with gdb. Output was not very helpful...

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: 
/home/foo/apptest/build/apptest 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffffffc9b0 in ?? ()
```

I assume linking is not done properly, but why? How can I resolve this without having to link OpenCV libs directly in app?

Comment: Does it work correctly when you include all the shared libs from `mylib.pro` file in your `apptest.pro` ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I only have "libopencv_*.so"s dynamically linked in `mylib.so`, when I add all these dependencies to `apptest.pro`, program compiles but crashes without exceptions.

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to reproduce your problem using CMake build system on Debian9 (you can try to use CMake in this case). Try to investigate the stacktrace (add -g to compiler flags) from crash. It might be an issue where 2 static libs try to deallocate the same resources, or it might be something totally different.

Comment: Well, I feel so dumb... Problem was, I was trying to read and write a `.jpg` image and apparently OpenCV was not compiled with the `jpg` support. I think I should delete the question, it is not helpful by any means.