# Linking shared library dependency not being listing in ldd

Tags: c++, c, makefile, shared-libraries, gnu

There is library which is compiled against -lyaml. But libyaml.so is not getting listed as dependency by ldd. Build is happening successfully using autoconf tool chain.

```
$ nm libxxxx.so | grep -i yaml
 U yaml_document_delete
 U yaml_document_get_node
 U yaml_parser_delete
 U yaml_parser_initialize
 U yaml_parser_load
 U yaml_parser_set_input_file


$ readelf -d libxxxx.so
    Tag        Type                         Name/Value
    0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
    0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libxxxx.so.0]
```

There is another shared library which depends depend upon libxxxx.so.

```
$ ldd  lib/libxxxx1.so
    libzmq.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5 (0x00007fd45e072000)
    libxmaapi.so.0 =>
```

When I am linking my executable with libxxxx1.so, it is giving undefined symbols error. The question is how do I link against library not found in dependency tree?

This question provides approaches to ignore the problem.
[Linking with dynamic library with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055569/linking-with-dynamic-library-with-dependencies)

Comment: Have you added your libyaml location to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I dislike how people come, ask incomplete questions, and then leave...

Comment: There are so many ways the linking could go wrong. without being able to reproduce we can only guess.

Comment: @YSC Yes I have added that.

Answer (score 1):

The one approach which I found is disabling optimization using the gcc flag  -Wl,--no-as-needed. Since I am already linking using -lyaml, symbols are getting resolved. It works but not efficient.