# Do I have to link to dependencies of my dependencies?

Tags: c++, linker

Im building a shared library which itself has a dependency on another shared library.
These dependencies are not exposed by the library, for example

**In Library A:**

```
class MySubDependencyClass{

}
```

**In Library B:**

```
class MyLibraryClass{
public:
   void foo(){
      mySubDependencyClass.foo()
   }
private:
MySubDependencyClass mySubDependencyClass;
}
```

**In my Application:**

```
class MyAppClass{
  MyLibraryClass myLibrary class
}
```

The dependency chain looks like this MyApp -> MyLibrary ->MySubDependency

When building MyApp at the moment I have to link the subdependencies as well as the direct dependency. Is there any way to get around this? It seems very unelegant.

I found this link:
[Linking with dynamic library with dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055569/linking-with-dynamic-library-with-dependencies) 
but couldn't understand if the issue was resolved or not

My IDE is qtcreator.

EDIT:

I have now forward declared the subdependency

**In Library B:**

```
class MySubDependencyClass;

class MyLibraryClass{
public:
   void foo(){
      mySubDependencyClass.foo()
   }
private:
MySubDependencyClass mySubDependencyClass;
}
```

and this works, is this the way to go? What is the "standard" way of dealing with this?

Comment: Do you use any of the SubDependency functions in your application?

Comment: "These dependencies are not exposed by the library" this is not correct, just because `mySubDependencyClass` is private doesn't mean it is not part of your libraries interface. There needs to be no instances of library a's classes in library b's public headers

Comment: @vahancho no i do not, or if i do, then they are wrapped

Comment: @AlanBirtles How would i wrap the subdependency correctly to get around this?

Comment: either hide it completely using the pimpl pattern or you might be able to get away with forward declaring `MySubDependencyClass` in `MyLibraryClass` and making `mySubDependencyClass` a pointer (preferrably a smart one)

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks, the forward declaration worked, ill check out the pimpl pattern